# Change size of out.write buffer

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I have to debug some legacy code. There are lot of servlets, jsp, compiled jsp, jspf, JavaScript etc. The hardest part is that JSP pages are precompiled and deployed in JBoss so all I can do is to remotely debug compiled instead of source pages. I have a source, but of course eclipse debugger is stepping through this_and_that_jsp.java.

The problem is that there is lot of HTML and even worse JavaScript code generated in those JSP pages. The only way to find where it breaks is to observe response (HttpServletResponse) CharArrayWriter step by step as it generates HTML page.

The problem is that it writes (of course) every 8192 characters. So, I can see the page (HTML with JavaScript) just before error and after it, but I can't catch exact moment. What would be solution to this? Should I decrease buffer size to 1 or so? I can't put 'flush' because I don't not where it breaks, I have to step through code line by line (or at least block by block). Where should I change buffer size for HttpServletResponse?

[image]

Comment: can you modify the web.xml to add a own servlet filter to the application?

Comment: @wero I am not quite sure how to do it. Can you give any example on that?

Comment: your app contains servlets and compiled jsp which are essentially also servlets. A servlet receives requests and creates responses. Filters allow you to intercept requests before they reach a servlet. In your case you may want to install a Filter which reconfigures the size of the response buffer or (more complicated solution) to wrap the response to let it return a more debug friendly writer. Hard to explain in a comment. http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/onjava/2001/05/10/servlet_filters.html has an introduction on the topic.

Comment: I know this part: "your app contains servlets and compiled jsp which are essentially also servlets. A servlet receives requests and creates responses." :) But I am not familiar with "Filters" part at all. Feel free if you have time to elaborate on that in answer not in comment. Anyway, thank you I'll read material from that link you gave me.